# Why is restful_authentication not available as a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Why is `restful_authentication` not available as a gem that we can put into Gemfile?

In the documentation it says we should put it in the `vendor` directory.
Is there a difference between having libraries in a Gemfile or under `vendor` such as different behavior or loading hooks?

Comment: Rails 3.2 deprecates `vendor/plugins`, and they'll be unsupported in 4.0. That's the main difference these days.

Answer (score 3):

[restful_authentication](https://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication) hasn't been updated in some time, and should certainly not be used for new Rails apps (and I'd suggest moving any old apps to a different authentication system if possible). I'd recommend instead taking a look at these other authentication gems:

- [Authlogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic)
- [Clearance](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance)
- [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)
- [OmniAuth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth)
- [Sorcery](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery)

You can also always [roll your own solution](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch).